# How do I debug a failing DB write with Doctrine and Symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a controller I have this after a form is submitted and `isValid()`

```
// ...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($form->getData());
$em->flush();
// ...
```

I have checked the contents of `$form->getData()` and it looks fine but it's not writing it to the table. I'm not getting any errors in the logs. How can I start debugging this?

Comment: Your code-example is too small to locate the problem precisely, however I guess that the entity is not available to the entitiy manager. Are you using a valid entity to store the forms data? - see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#forms-and-doctrine for the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, this snippet is too small. I was hoping there was a way to see what Doctrine was trying to do e.g. getSqlQuery(). Actually my problem was I needed to use Lifecycle Callbacks to set a `created` date. Problem was compounded as I was using AJAX and missed the error response until I started using firebug. I assumed the same error would appear in the logs... live and learn!

Comment: You can make doctrine logging nearly anything, for example the SQL queries: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#sql-logger-optional - and please add what solved your issue as an answer below. I think more users can benefit from the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my Entity class, which was for user registration I had a date created field. In order to populate this field I had

```
// this is the WRONG version
class User{

    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;


    //...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }


    public function setCreated(\DateTime() $created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;
    }

}
```

However what I should have had is:

```
/** 
 * ... other orm settings
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    //....

    /**
     * @ORM\prePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedValue()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }

}
```

The reason I didn't spot this is that no error was logged to the log files. I was submitting this form as an ajax call and didn't think to look in the response for that ajax call for the error until I turned on firebug (was relying on the default chrome console)

I don't remember the exact error that can back but it was around the DateTimeType.

Comment: Needs to be \PrePersist on any platforms other than windows.